# How to use this in Prestashop 1.7 registerHook('customerAccount')?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

How to use this displayCustomerAccount ?
I want to display some info here /index.php?controller=my-account

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but this hook is specifically made to add links on index.php?controller=my-account's page, not any kind of text or info.

Anyway, to add elements on this page, first hook your module to customerAccount by adding $this->registerHook('customerAccount') in the install function of your module's class like so:

```
public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() ||
        !$this->registerHook('customerAccount')
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then add the following function to your module's class

```
public function hookCustomerAccount()
{
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'your_link' => $your_link,
        'any_variable_needed' => $any_variable_needed
    ));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'my_account.tpl');
}
```

Finally, create a new tpl file your_module_folder\views\templates\hook\my_account.tpl and add your info in it.
As I told previously, usually you will find a link like that:

```
<a class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="your_id" href="{$your_link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
      <span class="link-item">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE850;</i>
          {l s='Your link' mod='your_module'}
      </span>
</a>
```